# Getting Current Item of Higher Scope While Loop

Tags: powershell, loops

I have a nested switch statement inside a switch statement. I am wondering if it is possible to grab the un-nested current item within the scope of the nested switch statement. I know I can accomplish this with a for loop with moderate difficulty but I am hoping there is some elegance I am missing to accomplishing this with switch statements. Below I am try to build some argument processing for one of my scripts.

```
# Process Args
$currentArg
$recurseOn = $false

:ListArgs switch -regex ($args)
{
    "-ou?" { $currentArg = "Organizational Unit"; write-host "Noticed ou switch"}
    "-li?k?e?" { $currentArg = "Compare To"; write-host "Noticed like switch"}
    "^-re?c?u?r?s?e?$" { $recurseOn = $true; write-host "Recurse switched on..."}
    default {
        :CurrentSwitch switch ($currentArg)
        {
            "Organizational Unit" { $OU = $_.$_ ; write-host "OU changed to '$($OU)'..."}
            "Compare To" { $Match = $_.$_ ; write-host "Lookup changed to '$($Match)'..."}
        }
    }
}
```

I know the present model of $*.$* does not work but I am looking for something that could refer to the current item. I am thinking I could have a filler variable that I just fill with the current item regardless of condition and use that within the scope, but maybe there is something more elegant. I have also tried labeling my switch statements and attempted 'ListArgs.$_' to no avail.

Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I did this after posting:

```
    # Process Args
$currentArg
$recurseOn = $false

:ListArgs switch -regex ($args)
{
    "-ou?" { $currentArg = "Organizational Unit"; write-host "Noticed ou switch"}
    "-li?k?e?" { $currentArg = "Compare To"; write-host "Noticed like switch"}
    "^-re?c?u?r?s?e?$" { $recurseOn = $true; write-host "Recurse switched on..."}
    default {
        $item = $_
        :CurrentSwitch switch ($currentArg)
        {
            "Organizational Unit" { $OU = $item; write-host "OU changed to '$($OU)'..."}
            "Compare To" { $Match = $item; write-host "Lookup changed to '$($Match)'..."}
        }
    }
}
```

And was able to get it working, but any input on $_ or loop labels would be appreciated. Or is there a better way to do arg processing in PowerShell?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. `$item = $_` is how I would do it.

Comment: Yeah it appears that is the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since there are no better suggestions out there for argument processing, I answered my own question.

```
    $item = $_
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking I could have a filler
>   variable that I just fill with the
>   current item regardless of condition
>   and use that within the scope

Usually I do this and I do not know a better way. Thus, your code would be:

```
...
default {
    $filler = $_
    :CurrentSwitch switch ($currentArg)
    {
        "Organizational Unit" { use $filler in here }
        "Compare To" { use $filler in here }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you have done it already after posting. The code is just fine, IMHO.

Comment: And indeed, the same trick will be needed in similar situations, not just `switch`, everything dealing with `$_`: `switch`, For-EachObject, $_ as event args in event handlers, and quite a few of others. `$_` is slightly overloaded too much sometimes.